# How to check if INSERT IGNORE has actually inserted the row from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem,I don't know how to check if my MySql query has actually inserted or ignored the insert from my php code.
This is because as far as I know it always returns true, due to the error preventing of the ignore clause.
A sample of what I have is:

```
$addTagSql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (text) 
  VALUES ('$text')";
$resultAddTag = $db -> query($addTagSql);

if(!$resultAddTag) {
  $response["success"] = 0;
}
else{
  $response["success"] = 1;
}
```

Should I just let it break and handle the error?
I couldn't find a good answer, so I'd be glad if you can help me :)

Comment: You can use `ROW_COUNT()`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is that reliable? Imagine that I have several accesses deleting, inserting and updating at the same time, I think that could mess it up at some point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mysqli_affected_rows()`

reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 4):

You can try with [`$mysqli->affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/pl/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 2):

`insert ignore` used to ignore the error, you can use `insert` and check if it return sql error or not.